# Could the sum of two normally distributed random variables be a GEV distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab, extreme-value

I'm playing with Matlab, I have got a test statistic $T$ wich is of the form :
$$T(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_{i}(x)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}g_{i}(x)+c $$
Where $f$ and $g$ are functions of the observations $x$, $n$ is the obeservations length and $c$ is a constant. Now, doing some simulation and using the Matlab "Distribution fitting" app, the distribution of $T$ seems to be a Generalized Extreme Value distribution [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution), here's what I got on Matlab:

[image]
The red graph is the GEV distribution. I checked the distribution of $f$ and $g$, and it seems that they both have a Normal distribution:

[image]

**MY QUESTION IS** is it possible that the sum of 2 normal distributed variables  to be a GEV distribution?

Comment: 1. In what sense do you mean "converges to"? What sequence of things are you referring to? 2. Do you happen to have a scatter plot of the two things you're adding?

Comment: @Glen_b, I modified my question. Here's the scatter plot for $A=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_{i}(x)$ and $B=\sum_{i=1}^{n}g_{i}(x)$: http://i.imgur.com/RzMIHIx.png

Comment: They're almost perfectly negatively correlated!

Comment: @Glen_b, how can this help answer my question?

Comment: It may be valuable for people who are trying to figure out a suitable bivariate distribution that will make the sum have close to the same appearance.